# attach iframe with remote content to dojo container

Tags: iframe, dojo, cross-domain

I'm pretty new to dojo and was wondering how I could have an iframe within a dojo container - either a content pane or a borderContainer (I don't need to access anything in the iframe and don't need to load it via ajax - just plop it into a content pane in my application. If I could somehow bypass having dojo try to load stuff I think that might somehow lead to a solution. I've tried POJS (plain old javascript) and I can't seem to load the content pane directly because of the cross domain considerations introduced by loading via ajax of course.  I've tried:

- using the content and a content string `'<iframe id="a" name="a" src="http://google.com"></iframe>'`
- using dojo.iframe.send with specifying the url
- using dojo.io.script.get
- dojo.create to create the iframe element

While the iframe.send did seem to return data (it looked like a valid page return), I didn't know how set the content for the iframe.  Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstand you, but setting the content of a ContentPane to be an iframe shouldn't be a problem.

```
dijit.byId("targetPane").set("content", dojo.create("iframe", {
    "src": "http://www.stopacta.info",
    "style": "border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%"
}));
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/froden/8NemY/

Comment: Nope, you didn't misunderstand - new @ dojo!  I was overthinking on loading the content asynchronously through dojo instead of just creating a dom element (which is what I did in js in the code).  This is much more elegant than an odd few lines of plain js in the container, thank you!